# Reading .bson file with Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, binary, bson, raw

I was very curious about .bson binary file produced by [mongodump](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/).
At first, my guessing was BSON Array `Bson::Array(array_of_documents)`
Then:

```ini
#Cargo.toml

[dependecies]
...
bson = "2.1.0"
```

```rust
//main.rs
fn main()
{
    let mut path=std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    path.push("backup/transactions.bson");

    if path.exists() {
        match std::fs::File::open(&path)
        {
            Err(err)=>panic!("Failed to open '{}'",path.to_str().unwrap(),err),
            Ok(file)=>{
                if let Ok(bson_file)=bson::Bson::from_reader(&file) {
                    if let Some(bson_array)=bson_file.as_array() {
                        for bson_data in bson_array {
                            println!("BSON Data: {:?}",&bson_data);
                        }
                    }  else {
                        println!("Not an array");
                    }
                } else {
                    println!("Not a BSON file");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I ran:

```bash
$ cargo run
...
Not an array
```

Clearly a BSON file, but not an array! What was it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I thought.. what if it was a Document `Bson::Document(bson_data)`?

```rust
//main.rs
fn main()
{
    let mut path=std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    path.push("backup/transactions.bson");

    if path.exists() {
        match std::fs::File::open(&path)
        {
            Err(err)=>panic!("Failed to open '{}'",path.to_str().unwrap(),err),
            Ok(mut file)=>{
                if let Ok(doc_data)=bson::Document::from_reader(&mut file) {
                   //Print all keys of the document
                   println!("Document keys: {:?}",doc_data.keys().map(|x| x.as_str()).collect::<Vec<&str>>());
                } else {
                   println!("Not a document");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
$ cargo run
...
["_id","code","type","customerName","items","createdAt"]
```

Those keys are my Transaction data! 
But it only retrieves one document and prints all keys of the document. Where are the rest of those documents? I have more than 50 documents dumped in .bson file.
Then I suspected something, what if.. a .bson file is consisted of a series of documents being placed next to the other.

```rust
//main.rs
fn main()
{
    let mut path=std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    path.push("backup/transactions.bson");

    if path.exists() {
        match std::fs::File::open(&path)
        {
            Err(err)=>panic!("Failed to open '{}'",path.to_str().unwrap(),err),
            Ok(mut file)=>{
                //Read file size
                let n=file.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::End(0)).unwrap_or(0);

                //Put file pointer at the beginning of file
                if file.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::Start(0)).is_ok() {
                    //Hold the number of retrieved documents
                    let mut i=0_u16;

                    //Read only 50 documents or end of file has been reached
                    while i < 50 && file.stream_position().unwrap_or(0) < n {
                       if let Ok(doc_data) = bson::Document::from_reader(&mut file) {
                           println!("Document: {}. {:?}",i+1,&doc_data);
                           i+=1;
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
$ cargo run
...
Document: 1. Document({"_id": ObjectId("63ee1b8b4b7c65e95ba891bd"), "originalId": ObjectId("6252fab17b201412088a4aaa"), "client": ObjectId("63d62de44370c4d5f1670f78"), "type": String("room"),...
...
Document: 36. Document({"_id": ObjectId("63ee1b8b4b7c65e95ba891e7"), "originalId": ObjectId("625300cb7b201412088a4d30"), "client": ObjectId("63d62de44370c4d5f1670f78"),...
```

Yes..my guessing was right. A .bson file is a series of `Bson::Document(data)` being placed next to the other

Comment: it's not uncommon to use new line as separator but here there is not even separator, one exception among many in mongo stack, thus this one is technical, it's more simple to parse document by document and not create a giant vector of document while parsing.

Comment: @Stargateur ..yea. BSON deserializer knows where the start/end its data. It's convenient. You can send BSON binary data over the network, without worrying about start/end flags of a data.